# Add a quick field in quick create form in Microsoft CRM

Tags: forms, crm

I am learning how to use Microsoft Dynamics CRM and I have a question according to the Quick Create form. So I have built a Quick Create Form for Contacts but I want to add a quick field(Quick View form) into that form. Seems like because it is already a Quick Create form, there are no options for Quick View form in the insert area except from Spacer and Timer. Do you have any idea if that could be done actually and if yes, how? Do I have to create it from another section?

Comment: `but I want to add a quick field(Quick View form) into that form` ? Please elaborate more, try adding screen captures.

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM I wanted to add a Quick View form in a Quick create form. But unfortunately I can't so I will probably have to add it a separate field.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot add a Quick View Form to a Quick Create form:

> While quick create forms support form scripts and business rules, their purpose is different from main forms and they don’t support all the capabilities of main forms. Quick create forms always have one section with three columns. You can’t add additional sections or columns.
>
> The following controls cannot be added to quick create forms:
>
> - Sub-grids
> - Quick View Forms
> - Web resources
> - IFRAMEs
> - Notes
> - Bing Maps
>
> If you add a composite field to a quick create form, it will be displayed as separate fields.

[More information](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531126.aspx)

Comment: Thank you @FedericoJousset. I will propably add it as a separate field.